# Bootstrap Token Field inputType email is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, email, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using bootstrap and Token Field plugin to get multiple emails. I have mentioned like this.

`<input type="email" id="token-friend-email" class="friend-email form-control input-border input-style" value="" placeholder="" required>`

and

```
$('#token-friend-email').tokenfield({
    inputType : 'email',
    delimiter:';'

});
```

But the token field is accepting all types of input. I want only email type to be accepted. Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aL1hqn0v/)** check this demo

Html part

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="" />
```

This is the jquery part...

```
$('#tokenfield')

  .on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
    var data = e.attrs.value.split('|')
    e.attrs.value = data[1] || data[0]
    e.attrs.label = data[1] ? data[0] + ' (' + data[1] + ')' : data[0]
  })

  .on('tokenfield:createdtoken', function (e) {
    // Über-simplistic e-mail validation
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
    var valid = re.test(e.attrs.value)
    if (!valid) {
      $(e.relatedTarget).addClass('invalid')
    }
  })

  .on('tokenfield:edittoken', function (e) {
    if (e.attrs.label !== e.attrs.value) {
      var label = e.attrs.label.split(' (')
      e.attrs.value = label[0] + '|' + e.attrs.value
    }
  })

  .on('tokenfield:removedtoken', function (e) {
    alert('Token removed! Token value was: ' + e.attrs.value)
  })

  .tokenfield()
```

Comment: ThankQ  @shri ... Its working fine.. But one more thing , is it possible to remove wrongly entered value automatically when we click enter or , or tab?

Comment: if you find this solution is useful then upvote the answer and mark it as selected..

Comment: @Shanthi it is possible to remove invalid email  if valid==false then remove the email..

Answer (score 3):

I used the same @shri but i modified little bit.

Use

```
$(e.relatedTarget).empty().hide().attr('data-value', '');
```

instead of this

```
$(e.relatedTarget).addClass('invalid')
```

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aL1hqn0v/3/)** check this demo

Html part

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="" />
```

This is the jquery part...

```
$('#tokenfield')

  .on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
    var data = e.attrs.value.split('|')
    e.attrs.value = data[1] || data[0]
    e.attrs.label = data[1] ? data[0] + ' (' + data[1] + ')' : data[0]
  })

  .on('tokenfield:createdtoken', function (e) {
    // Über-simplistic e-mail validation
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
    var valid = re.test(e.attrs.value)
    if (!valid) {
      $(e.relatedTarget).addClass('invalid')
    }
  })

  .on('tokenfield:edittoken', function (e) {
    if (e.attrs.label !== e.attrs.value) {
      var label = e.attrs.label.split(' (')
      e.attrs.value = label[0] + '|' + e.attrs.value
    }
  })

  .on('tokenfield:removedtoken', function (e) {
    alert('Token removed! Token value was: ' + e.attrs.value)
  })

  .tokenfield()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi @shri i have tried using this
we can also use this

$(e.relatedTarget).empty().hide()

instead of

$(e.relatedTarget).empty().hide().attr('data-value', '');